# force close in creating simplecursor adapter

Tags: android, database, simplecursoradapter

I have the following code which should display in a list the content from a database (a certain table and a certain column) but I get a force close dialog and I don't know why.

This is my code:

```
public class Server8 extends Activity {

DBAdapter db;

    @Override
    public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {

       setContentView(R.layout.main);

       db=new DBAdapter(this);
       db.openDataBase();
       Cursor cursor=db.getAllData2();

       startManagingCursor(cursor);

       String[] from=new String[] {db.KEY_ROUTE};     

       int[] to = new int[] { R.id.name_entry};

       ContactListCursorAdapter items = new ContactListCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.list_example_entry, cursor, from, to);
    }

    public class ContactListCursorAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter{

        private Context context;

        private int layout;

        public ContactListCursorAdapter (Context context, int layout, Cursor c, String[] from, int[] to) {
            super(context, layout, c, from, to);
            this.context = context;
            this.layout = layout;
        }

        @Override
        public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {

            Cursor c = getCursor();

            final LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

            View v = inflater.inflate(layout, parent, false);

            int nameCol = c.getColumnIndex(db.KEY_ROUTE);
            String name = c.getString(nameCol);

            TextView name_text = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.name_entry);
            if (name_text != null) {
                name_text.setText(name);
            }

            return v;
        }

        @Override
        public void bindView(View v, Context context, Cursor c) {

            int nameCol = c.getColumnIndex(db.KEY_ROUTE);
            String name = c.getString(nameCol);

            TextView name_text = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.name_entry);

            if (name_text != null) {
                name_text.setText(name);
            }
        }
```

---

In my DBAdapter  I have this:

```
public static final String TABLE_2= "route";

public static final String KEY_ROWID_2="_id";

public static final String KEY_ROUTE= "route";

public static final String KEY_USER_ID= "user_id";
```

This is how I query for the cursor:

```
public Cursor getAllData2() 
{
    return db.query(TABLE_2, new String[] {KEY_ROUTE},null,null,null,null,null);
}
```

---

and this is what my logcat gives me:

04-30 09:26:24.323: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2676): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column '_id' does not exist

04-30 09:26:24.323: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2676):     at android.database.AbstractCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(AbstractCursor.java:314)

04-30 09:26:24.323: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2676):     at android.widget.CursorAdapter.init(CursorAdapter.java:111)

04-30 09:26:24.323: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2676):     at android.widget.CursorAdapter.(CursorAdapter.java:90)

04-30 09:26:24.323: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2676):     at android.widget.ResourceCursorAdapter.(ResourceCursorAdapter.java:47)

04-30 09:26:24.323: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2676):     at android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter.(SimpleCursorAdapter.java:88)

04-30 09:26:24.323: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2676):     at com.server.Server8$ContactListCursorAdapter.(Server8.java:103)

04-30 09:26:24.323: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2676):     at com.server.Server8.onCreate(Server8.java:91)

---

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column '_id' does not exist

I'm not even asking for something like this!!

and this is what my `TABLE_2` looks like:

```
_id         route                  user_id

1           Sebes-Alba               1             ....only one record
```

What I'm doing wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your table has a column named `_id`.  The common approach is to create the _id column as `_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT`.
Then, make sure you always query for the `_id` with each query to the database.

References:

[Details on column ID issues](http://www.anddev.org/view-layout-resource-problems-f27/column-id-doesnt-exist-t12189.html)

[How to create a column](http://php.about.com/od/mysqlcommands/g/sql_add_column.htm)

Comment: it has _id..........so this query is not good:                     return db.query(TABLE_2, new String[] {KEY_ROUTE},null,null,null,null,null);   ?

Comment: try it with the `KEY_ROWID_2` like so `return db.query(TABLE_2, new String[] {KEY_ROWID_2, KEY_ROUTE},null,null,null,null,null);`

Answer (score 0):

Your log says that there is no `_id` column in the target of your query (table):

> column '_id' does not exist

You should verify if you have a column in your `route` table named `_id`, and if there is difference, you should update your `public static final String KEY_ROWID_2`.

Comment: I understand that I'm asking for such a column and it does not exists...but I'm not asking for it....and yes it exists...what should I do with it.........I don't understand what do u mean by update my      public static final STring KEY_......